# Minimum number of moves to make matrices equal

Tags: number-theory

**Given:** Two $n × m$ matrices $A$ and $B$ with integer entries.
**To Do:**  Make them completely identical. To achieve this goal, perform the following actions in a single move:
1. Choose one of the matrices, either A or B.
2. Choose either one row or one column of the selected matrix.
3. Increment all the numbers in the selected row or column by 1.

What is the **minimal number of moves** to perform in order to make matrices A and B equal? Or is it just **impossible**?

**Ex:** A = [1 1; 1 1] and B = [2 2; 0 0]. So in 2 moves we can make them equal (inc 1st row of A, then inc 2nd row of B)

Comment: What do we know about the entries of the matrices. If no restrictions are given, it may be impossible: if $B$ only has integers entries and then $a_{11} = 0.5$ for example

Comment: Both have Integer entries. And there still might be cases when its impossible.

Comment: Yes, there are cases where it is impossible. What do you wish to know then?

Comment: Minimal number of moves to make them equal.

Comment: As it is worded, we cannot provide a full answer, given that there may be cases where it is impossible and cases where it is possible. I doubt that you just want us to answer you "there are cases where it is possible; cases where it is impossible". plus, the minimal number of moves depends greatly on the two matrices involved. I can find $A, B$ such that the answer is $k$, for any natural $k$ you pick.

Comment: We can represent a solution using programming language too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible if and only if the [Smith normal forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) agree. I suggest you figure out (this is not difficult) how to start with an integer matrix $C$ and produce the Smith normal form $PCQ,$ where $P,Q$ are square invertible of the appropriate two sizes. Finding the Smith form for two different matrices therefore gives a method for getting from one to the other. That is, if
$$ MAN = PBQ = S  $$
is a Smith form, then
$$ P^{-1}MAN Q^{-1} = B $$
You will need to do examples to write this in your "counting moves" style.